# vuejs v model instant update by selecting html

Tags: search, vue.js, model

I am very new to vue and have question.

I have following calendar in html.

```
<div class="year">2018</div>
<div class="month  disabled">JAN</div>
<div class="month  disabled">FEB</div>
<div class="month  disabled">MAR</div>
<div class="month  disabled">APR</div>
<div class="month  disabled">MAY</div>
<div class="month  disabled">JUN</div>
<div class="month  disabled">JUL</div>
<div class="month  disabled">AUG</div>
<div class="month  disabled">SEP</div>
<div class="month  disabled">OCT</div>
<div class="month  disabled">NOV</div>
<div class="month  ">DEC</div>
<br>

    <div class="year">2019</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">JAN</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">FEB</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">MAR</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">APR</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">MAY</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">JUN</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">JUL</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">AUG</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">SEP</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">OCT</div>
    <div class="month  disabled">NOV</div>
    <div class="month  ">DEC</div>
    <br>
    <div>
        {{product_list}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Everytime the user clicks the month, I want to update product_list shown only items in the same month. The month is multi selective. only div without disabled is selectable

For example, when user selects JAN, MAR in 2018, I want to show products which have date in JAN and MAR in 2018.

here is sameple product list

```
 $product = [
            "id" => 1,
            "productDates" => [
                ["id" => 109,
                    "product_id" => 10,
                    "departure_date" => "2018-12-11"
                ],
                ["id" => 110,
                    "product_id" => 10,
                    "departure_date" => "2018-3-11"
                ],
                ["id" => 109,
                    "product_id" => 10,
                    "departure_date" => "2019-12-11"
                ],
                ["id" => 110,
                    "product_id" => 10,
                    "departure_date" => "2018-4-11"
                ],
                ["id" => 109,
                    "product_id" => 10,
                    "departure_date" => "2018-4-12"
                ],
                ["id" => 110,
                    "product_id" => 10,
                    "departure_date" => "2018-5-21"
                ],
            ]
        ];


 var opVm = new Vue({
        el: "#departure-date-list",
        data: {
            seasons:{!! json_encode($seasons) !!},
            product:{!! json_encode($product) !!},
            productDates:{!! json_encode($product->productDates) !!},
            datePax:{!! json_encode($datePax) !!},
        },
        methods: {
            select:function(year,month){
                console.log(year);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have done this.